# JavaScriptSerializer Serialize() method failing to return a very large json string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a web service function from which i am getting almost 100 000 records.

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = OdbcHelper.ExecuteDataset(Connection.ODBCConnection(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "{ CALL Search_SP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", p);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);

        }
        return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

This is my javascript:-

```
  var Data = Search(//passing parameters of function//);

        var data = "";
        data = Data['Search'];
        Data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

When I debug the code i found that my stored procedure also works fine. It takes less than 5 secs to execute and fetch more than 50 000 records. But "return serializer.Serialize(rows);" is taking so much time to return json string.
If the number of rows are 100 it takes 30-35 secs and for 100k records it almost dies. Doesn't return any output.Appears like the application gets hanged.

I am not able to understand why its taking so much time.The number of records in my database are going to increase every day by 50 000 more.

Comment: If you know the expected result, try serialising manually, i.e. `for.. json += '{foo: "bar"}'`, it may be faster as you'd be assuming types rather than testing each type

Comment: There is no way that querying and showing 100,000 rows of data to the user will result in a usable application. Especially if the data grows by 50,000 rows a day. Consider pagination or on-demand partial loading.

Comment: Its not that i need to fetch all records in database but i will have to show atleast 100000 records minimum.I have already used pagination in grid.But serialize method itself is taking so much time to return data

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change serializer to netwonsoft [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Also you could creat a leaner class than datarow, and serialize that one instead, another suggestion is to split this call in smaller batches (like pagination)

code sample:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  var myObj = new MyClass();
  myObj.MyColumn = dr["MyColumn"];
  .. // and so on all your columns as properties on MyClass
}
return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Comment: how can i split this call in smaller batches?any idea?I dont have any idea about leaner class.

Comment: changed sample to a poco (plain old clr object) wich is a leaner object than datarow.  , to split you have to get  N number of rows and then get the next N number of rows a bit more complex but I think it is the only way to send 100k lines

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another serializer like  [Newtosoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text)